# How can an attacker create a key pair with the same (short) KeyID

Tags: security, pgp

Alice gets Bob's public key (either in email or from a server), then calls Bob on the phone and checks his short KeyID.

There are 16^8 ~ 4.3 billion possible KeyIDs consisting of 8 hex characters.

Is it feasible for an attacker to generate a database with 4.3 billion keys to cover all the possible IDs with specific name, email address, and date??
Can Date, Name and Email can be changed after it is created.

Is it not correct to assume that creating 4 billion 4K keys for each attack seems out of questions.

A related question is about long KeyID this seems so secure that there should never be any need to use the fingerprint.

Is the caution against using short KeyIDs just paranoia without base in reality?
I am talking about 3k and 4k keys.

Thank you in advance for your kind help with this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not about software development, but information security. Anyway, I already [provided a discussion of the Evil32 attack on the Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/74009/19837), which answers your question.

Comment: Well, in my case it is about software developing.
I am working on making an easy to use front end to PGP email.
And need to determine whether I really need to use long KeyID, or is the short KeyID sufficiently safe for direct verification.

Comment: The question is not software development _specific_, unless you did not mention something relevant changing the question's scope. Asking on the right place also means getting the right people to answer your question.

Comment: Well, OK.
Where is the "delete" button?

Comment: Have no idea where I should ask this question...